# Firebase child event listerner

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying use firebase use the child event listerner but its running on the activty has started and adding data into my realm

is there any way that it must run only while data changed?

i am running in it oncreate

```
chatchildevntlistener = chatlistreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Constant.l("Add Changed Listerner Running");
                Conversion_List chatconbersionlist = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversion_List.class);
                if (chatconbersionlist.getReceiverid().equals(Session.getUserID(getApplicationContext())) && chatconbersionlist.getSenderid().equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("rid"))) {
                    chatrealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    chatrealm.beginTransaction();
                    final Chat_history_pojo chatupdatepojo = chatrealm.createObject(Chat_history_pojo.class);
                    int nextID = chatrealm.where(Chat_history_pojo.class).max("chatnumber").intValue() + 1;
                    chatupdatepojo.setChatnumber(nextID);
                    chatupdatepojo.setSenderid(chatconbersionlist.getSenderid());
                    chatupdatepojo.setReceiverid(chatconbersionlist.getReceiverid());
                    chatupdatepojo.setTimeofthemessage(chatconbersionlist.getTimeofthemessage());
                    chatupdatepojo.setType(chatconbersionlist.getType());
                    chatupdatepojo.setMessage(chatconbersionlist.getMessage().replace("$", " "));
                    chatupdatepojo.setSender_profile(chatconbersionlist.getSender_profile());
                    chatupdatepojo.setReciever_profile(chatconbersionlist.getReciever_profile());
                    chatupdatepojo.setImageprice("0");
                    chatupdatepojo.setReadstatus(0);
                    if (!chatconbersionlist.getPoofingtext().equals("0")) {
                        chatupdatepojo.setPoofingtext(Integer.parseInt(chatconbersionlist.getPoofingtext()));
                        Intent poofingintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Poofing_Receiver.class);
                        poofingintent.putExtra("rid", chatconbersionlist.getReceiverid());
                        poofingintent.putExtra("chatnumberposition", nextID);
                        PendingIntent poofingpendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), nextID, poofingintent, 0);
                        AlarmManager poofingalaramanager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        poofingalaramanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + Integer.parseInt(chatconbersionlist.getPoofingtext()) * 1000, poofingpendingintent);
                    }
                    chatrealm.commitTransaction();
                    chatrealm.close();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
//                Constant.l(dataSnapshot.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Constant.l(databaseError.toString());
            }
        });
        chatlistreference.addChildEventListener(chatchildevntlistener);
```

Comment: post activity code to better help

Comment: `onChildAdded` will run once at first, then as children are added... if that is your concern

Comment: If you need to do stuff only if child changes you need to do code inside this method **onChildChanged()**

Comment: But when child added then child add will run na

Comment: @cricket_007 yes its my concern